# storing time in a string C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm using the following code to store the time, But I'm wondering if it's possible to store this content in a string rather than char. Or maybe there's a method to store time in a string .

```
    ofstream read_file;
    read_file.open("time.txt");// file name
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char currenttime [80];

    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
    strftime (currenttime,80," %T",timeinfo);
    cout << " \n\n\n\n";
    cout << currenttime;    // time store section
   read_file << currenttime;
   read_file.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right thing, and, basically, what you would like to do, as I understood, is to keep the time in the `std::string` rather than `char currenttime [80]`. I would suggest the following things then:

1. Create a function that receives `time_t` as argument, and returns `std::string`
2. Copy your code from `struct tm* timeinfo` to `strftime` including, and add `return currenttime ;`
3. Use your function. Example: `const std::string filetime = time2string( rawtime );`

Note that there will be an automatic conversion from `char[]` to `std::string` when you call `return currenttime ;`

Note, that the suggestion below is to make code nicer and reusable. You can always add one more line after `strftime` : `const std::string ftime( currenttime ) ;`, and then start using `ftime` instead of `currenttime`. That will also work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
string timeToString()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char currenttime [80];

    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
    strftime (currenttime,80," %T",timeinfo);
    return currenttime;
}
```

Comment: `return currenttime` invokes `strlen` to determine the length of `currenttime`. `strftime` returns you that length, so you may like to use it to avoid the unnecessary `strlen` call, e.g. `return std::string(currenttime, strftime (currenttime,80," %T",timeinfo));`.